# How to fix "java.net.SocketException" error in java

Tags: java, sockets, exception, serversocket

Error on close client window and when open new client window appear error in server terminal. My english is rusty :P

Server error on closing client

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at main.java.Manager.run(Manager.java:45)
```

Client error on reopen to get object

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720013
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
    at main.java.controllers.VendedoresUI.load(VendedoresUI.java:69)
    at main.java.controllers.VendedoresUI.initialize(VendedoresUI.java:54)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at main.java.controllers.Controller.loadUI(Controller.java:150)
    at main.java.controllers.Controller.changeUI(Controller.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

1.Server classes

1.1. Server.java
    public class Server extends Thread{

```
    public Server(){}

    public void run() {

        try{

            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(4444);
            listener.setSoTimeout(0);

            System.out.println("Server is now running");

            try {
                while (true) {

                    Socket socket = listener.accept();

                    new Manager(socket).start();
                }
            } finally {
                listener.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioexception){

            System.out.println("\u001B[31mError opening server, more info: ");
            System.out.println(ioexception);
            System.out.println("Closing server...");
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }

}
```

1.2. Manager.java

```
public class Manager extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public Manager(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
        System.out.println("\u001B[32m" + socket.getLocalAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort() + " connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            out.println("Connected");

            while(true) {
                ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));



                if(in.readLine().contains(Protocols.VENDEDOR_GET_ALL)) {
                    ResultSet res = SQLManager.Query("SELECT * FROM vendedores");
                    List list = new ArrayList();

                    while (res.next()) {
                        Vendedor vendedor = new Vendedor();
                        vendedor.setNOME(res.getString("NOME"));
                        vendedor.setCPF(res.getString("CPF"));
                        vendedor.setCONTATO(res.getString("CONTATO"));
                        vendedor.setCONTA(res.getInt("CONTA"));
                        vendedor.setBANCO(res.getInt("BANCO"));
                        vendedor.setAGENCIA(res.getString("AGENCIA"));
                        vendedor.setCORRENTE(res.getString("CORRENTE"));
                        list.add(vendedor);
                    }
                    objectOutput.writeObject(list);
                }
                objectOutput.flush();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("\u001B[31m" + socket.getLocalAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort() + " disconnected");
            e.printStackTrace();
            interrupt();
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }

    }
}
```

2.Client classes

2.1. ClientSocket.java

```
public class ClientSocket {

    private static Socket socket = null;
    private static BufferedReader in;
    private static PrintWriter out;

    public static void load(){
        try {

            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            System.out.print(ClientSocket.getIn().readLine());

        } catch(IOException ioexception){
            Logger.getLogger(ClientSocket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ioexception);
        }
    }

    public static Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public static BufferedReader getIn() {
        return in;
    }

    public static PrintWriter getOut() {
        return out;
    }
}
```

2.2 VendedoresUI.java

```
public class VendedoresUI implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView table;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn colName;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn colCPF;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn colContato;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn colConta;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn colBanco;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn colAgencia;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn colCorrente;

    ObservableList list;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        load();

    }

    private void load(){
        try {
            if(ClientSocket.getSocket().isClosed()){
                ClientSocket.load();
            }

            PrintWriter escritor = new PrintWriter(ClientSocket.getSocket().getOutputStream(), true);

            escritor.println(Protocols.VENDEDOR_GET_ALL);


            ObjectInputStream obi = new ObjectInputStream(ClientSocket.getSocket().getInputStream());
            List mList = (List) obi.readObject();

            list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(mList);

            colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("NOME"));
            colCPF.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("CPF"));
            colContato.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("CONTATO"));
            colConta.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("CONTA"));
            colBanco.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("BANCO"));
            colAgencia.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("AGENCIA"));
            colCorrente.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("CORRENTE"));
            table.setItems(list);

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first problem: Server error on closing client, before closing client, inform Server and allow Server to stop processing. You can probably ignore this exception but it be nice to have orderly connection close.

On second problem, Client error on reopen (java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header): 
After debugging, I found the problem. The code below shows where the problem is.

Copy Paste and run as Junit to see it.

```
import org.junit.Test;    
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;    
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class ServerSocketTest {

    /**
     * Runs first to start server. This is the corrected server
     */
    @Test
    public void startServerTest() throws Exception {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(4444);
        while (true) {
            try (Socket socket = listener.accept()) {
                new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true).println("Connected");
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())).readLine();//read "ALL" from client
                new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()).writeObject("String Object");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Run client Twice to see error
     */
    @Test
    public void startClientTest() throws Exception {
        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);
        out.println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream())).readLine());
        new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true).println("ALL");//tell server we want all the data
        out.println(new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream()).readObject());
    }

    /**
     * This implementation will error out on second test
     */
    @Test
    public void errorServerTest() throws Exception {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(4444);
        while (true) {
            try (Socket socket = listener.accept()) {
                new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true).println("Connected");
                /*
                * Issue is here. The sequence of object construction matters.
                * The Constructor has side effects. To correct, move this contructor below InputStreamReader.
                * */
                ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())).readLine();//read "ALL" from client
                objectOutputStream.writeObject("String Object");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the issue is with the sequence of object creation between BufferedReader and ObjectOutputStream.

To fix your error, construct ObjectOutputStream last.